# What happened to my profile picture?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, gravatar, avatar

I've never added a profile picture to my account, and today it randomly changed.

**Original:**

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/826884b34e56417c12f2c0882b125376?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1
```

[image: original]

**New:**

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d82e9c986bd14027251dd29c7dc6478f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=y&so-version=2
```

[image: new]

Anyone know why this picture is changed? This only applies to SO and Meta SO, but remains the same in other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Mine changed too, but only in SO and meta SE

Comment: My money is on gravatar changing their avatar algorithm. You don't have any trace of a profile pic change in your history either (this happened to someone in chat as well, with no history trace), so gravatar silently doing some stuff that's currently in the middle of propagating to production doesn't sound too far-fetched

Comment: [Happened to me as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424668/profile-picture-changed-automatically-2023); looks like the Gravatar URL and the hash code in its path changed automatically. Also, for me it was first on stackoverflow.com only, but then also on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: ...but, who cares? If you want a static, predictable avatar that never changes, don't use a service that provides an arbitrary one based on a hash. Upload your own.

Comment: historically loosely/possibly related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250172/997587, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204523/997587. Also, I'm concerned about what this means for my collection of links to cool identicons (... don't ask me why I do this)

Comment: and a fresh post on MSE to add to the list: [Among my 27 main sites, my gravatar icon just changed, on its own, on just this site and the Stack Overflow main site (but not the meta one)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389100/997587)

Comment: It happened to me as well. The strange thing is: I'm pretty sure I have used "xxx@googlemail.com" as my mail address, but now it is "xxx@gmail.com". Change of the mail address would explain the change of the avatar.

Comment: @ead: My e-mail address did not change, yet my avatar did. The only thing that may have changed in my e-mail address is the case of the letters. It is possible that I used to have upper-case letters in my e-mail address and that these were changed to lower-case. Therefore, if the hash is generated from the e-mail address (of which I am unsure), and if my e-mail address indeed changed to lower-case characters (of which I am also unsure), then this would explain the avatar change.

Comment: Happened to me as well, it's different on SO and meta.SO that retained the original one. Weird. I also observed that clicking on the identicon in the profile settings would generate new ones every time. I thought this was stably linked to the email?

Comment: It hasn't changed for me. I think @ead may be on to something. Perhaps Gravatar decided to normalize some values in their database of email addresses, which would then change the avatar even if the algorithm hasn't changed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel **It has nothing to do with Gravatar** or an email address change: my identicon changed as well, but my email address is the same; **what's changed is a hash value in avatar URL** (as Marcono said) which is generated by SE. **I guess SE decided to change the salt value they add to the email**, but why this affects only a few sites and even different sites for different people that's the question...

Comment: @EvgenKo423 but then we'd expect everyone to be affected, no? It looks like this "bug" is only changing the avatar of a few users. Regarding the "googlemail" address, this isn't the case for me.

Comment: This happened to me also. I guess I'm going to have to make my own avatar image and figure out how to upload it, because even though I don't really care about it, I care enough to want consistency, and the random change is kind of annoying.

Comment: Something's definitely wrong. If I go to change my profile picture, every time I click it's a completely random profile picture [gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJek7.gif)

Comment: I've added a profile picture many years ago in Stackoverflow - and today I recognized it is gone. Is that a bug? Was there some maintenance in StackOverflow that destroyed it? I can see profile pictures of other people in StackOverflow are also affected (like Cesar M - see his answer below, his icon is gone).

Comment: @Stuckat1337 - The issue is, if you uploaded your own Avatar picture - it is gone now and a broken image icon is displayed instead.

Comment: @Matt No, that's not what this change did at all. Do you have an example? If you're seeing missing icons it is unrelated (Cesar's image below, for example, is not an identicon at all, it's hosted on imgur.com, and I can see it fine. If you see a broken image, the problem is likely on your end.)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 - I think it is solved, seems it was a temporary issue in imgur loading the icon. See  [meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imgur+%5Bbug%5D](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imgur+%5Bbug%5D)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This change is due to us forcibly changing all identicons across the Stack Exchange network.

We've done this for security reasons and you can read more in this MSE announcement: [We're regenerating all identicons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389123/were-regenerating-all-identicons).

Comment: Gee, thanks, I really love my identicon being changed from a pleasant green hue to a poo-brown one. /s Also why the frick is the change not being applied on ALL sites if this is done for "security reasons" - Meta-StackOverflow still shows me my pleasant old one, while some of the others show my new explosive-diarrhea one.

Answer (score -2):

Not only that - uploaded avatar pictures (like mine, uploaded many years ago) are gone now - showing a a broken image icon. I saw a couple of these in Stack Overflow - different users affected.

Something was terribly broken.

Comment: Did you fix it in the mean time? Because I've no problem seeing your avatar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1tMF.png

Comment: Did you use Identicon? Because your current avatar doesn't look like it. As for other users, do they also use Identicon/Gravatar? Not the badly broken [Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320818/241919)/[Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322761/241919) profile picture?

Comment: @AndrewT. - Sorry, I don't know what you're talking about. What I used is a plain picture which I uploaded to my profile.

Comment: What is Identicon/Gravatar ?

Comment: @Matt a service that generates an icon based on your email address (or other passed in unique value). You could also go to gravitar and upload your own image, thus allowing any website that sends your email address in to get an icon gets your submitted icon. Your problem is unrelated to the problem this question was about, given you uploaded your own image to SO directly.

Comment: @rene - No, I didn't upload any other picture since I noticed this issue. But thanks for the link, I will check it out and if I can access the picture I will re-upload it.

Comment: @rene - I followed your link then, when I came back to SO main page the image was visible there agein. Strange thing ... Must have been a caching issue.

Comment: So it works now? Maybe your connection to imgur was temporarily blocked or your local cache was corrupted. It feels more like a local/network issue then an issue on SE side of things.

Comment: do note that imgur issues have happened before for various reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imgur+%5Bbug%5D

Comment: @rene - Yes, all good now. Thank you for giving insights to the imgur-related issues that happened.